# Android app accessing the android dialer

Tags: android

Is it possible to access the dialer of android (mobile phone) from android app. Say if a user enters 001 in the app following by a telephone number, app should make the dialer of android(Mobile Phone) dial the number after 001...?

Answer (score 3):

You can send an Intent which will open de phone dialer with supplied phonenumber.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL

```
String url = "tel:1234";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
```

Don't forget to add the permission to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to send Intent with this action `Intent.ACTION_DIAL(android.intent.action.DIAL)` to see if it works.
ACTION_DIAL tel:123 -- Display the phone dialler with the given number filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code hope it helps

```
Intent sIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+00189899989));
startActivity(sIntent);
```